# How to execute shell script with default parameters

Tags: bash, makefile

I'm not sure if the title explain the real problem.

I have a shell script `load_config.sh`using `bash` shell. This script will load the configuration. Before starting to load the configuration, it prompt the user `"Do you want to load all configurations? Y/N ?"`. If the user choose "N" it does a different job with many questions prompting.

Now the real problem is; I have added this script to run in Makefile as below. My idea is to load all the configuration when I say `make install`, but then the script would prompt the user. I now donot want the script to prompt and it should take defaul 'Y' and install all configuration. How do I make this happen ?

```
.load_cfg.done : %
        @echo -e "\n* Loading configuration $<"
        $(PIN_HOME)/cfg/load_config.sh $<
        touch $@
```

Shell : BASH
OS : LINUX

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`yes`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/yes) command, in order to send a certain string into a user prompt.

For example, say your script looks like this:

```
$ cat loadConfig.sh
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Load all configuration? " -n 1 -r
if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
then
   echo "Loading all configuration"
else
   echo "Not loading all configuration"
fi
```

Pipe `yes` into your script:

```
$ yes | loadConfig.sh
Loading all configuration
```